# Regular Expression - Extract First Two Digit Value from String (Varying Format)

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to extract two digits from the following examples:

```
19-AB-4444
2-24-123-5564
09-7-1234
09-1234-ABC
1-11-1234-CCC
```

Results would be:

```
19
24
09
09
11
```

I tried to do this using lookbehinds with no luck. Note that there will always be a two digit number and this value will always be followed by some characters and one four digit number. There will not be more than one two digit and not more than one four digit number. I only need the 2 digit number.

Comment: How about `\b\d\d\b` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7gL9B8/1)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks!

Comment: how this entry `1-a-2-3-1223-AA` should be treated?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Based on the original description, I'd say that string isn't possible in the OP's data set. "There will always be a two-digit number...there will not be more than one two digit number..."

Answer (score 3):

To extract first 2 digits irrespective of word boundaries in a line you may use this regex:

```
^(?:(?!\d\d).)*(\d\d)
```

and grab captured group #1 as your target match.

`(?:(?!\d\d).)*` will match 0 or more of any characters that don't have 2 digits on right hand side.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7gL9B8/2)

---

However if your data is formatted as you showed in question then you may use simpler regex:

```
\b\d\d\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless Python is really slacking on its regex support, you should be able to just match against `[0-9]{2}`. That'll match the first occurrence of exactly 2 adjacent digits.